# How to upload image to Twitter API in C#?

Tags: c#, api, twitter

How can i upload a image to the Twitter API upload endpoint in C# but without any third party library?
i already tried the code in this SO question
[How to post a tweet on my twitter account using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52585806/how-to-post-a-tweet-on-my-twitter-account-using-c-sharp)
and it works pretty well but it just tweet text, i know that i have to attach the "media_id" parameter but first i need to upload the image to twitter and thats the problem i have

Comment: Why is it so important to not use a third party library - most of them have convenience methods that would make this more simple for you. If you’re stuck, I’d recommend looking at the source code for one of those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is how to send photos in a tweet, it might cause some other issues like Auth problems, twitter uses a parameter named `media_ids`
twitter let you upload a photo to https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json url and get an ID back then use it for your tweet.

in this post it used the media and solved Auth problem with OAtuh:
[Adding media_ids to Twitter API call causes authentication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063861)